# Can Sitecore templates be used to store SQL Queries or JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

We are building a Page with dynamic functionality using ASP.NET + Sitecore 7.0.

**Is it practical and appropriate use Sitecore templates for:**

1. SQL Stored Procedure Name to be invoked
2. JavaScript to be invoked
3. ColumnNames to be used etc (related to coding customization)

Or should these configuration properties remain inside the ASP.NET Project itself?

What is the primary purpose of Data Templates in Sitecore?
Are they for developer customization or customer-level customization?

Comment: Data templates are meant for the content authoring experience in Sitecore. That is not to say that you can't use a "configuration" or "storedproc" template to store that kind of information if you want to.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of a data template in Sitecore is to define the set of fields for content items which inherit from that template.  - Think of a data template as a class and the content items (pages) as instances of that class.

Templates are *usually* used to define the user-editable content of pages within a site, that being said you can have items to store information which is not managed by regular content editors.  The question is where do you draw the line between things which should be put into Sitecore and things which should be a part of the solution.  My advice is ***only put things in Sitecore if they need to be there***. If you ***have*** to have the ability for editors or admins to configure those settings/properties.

I would say that putting SQL/ColumnNames is probably a bad idea unless you are building some sort of report builder interface in which case it may be essential?

Likewise with placing JavaScript into Sitecore; this can be OK in moderation (e.g. snippets of analytics code which content editors may want control over?). If you're placing whole libraries of JavaScript into Sitecore, you're probably doing it wrong.

One final point to note is findability/re-factorability of code: if you have code spread between Sitecore and your solution, it can make it very difficult to maintain as it is difficult to get a complete overview of code involved.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers and suggestions. We will take it forward and after all we are aware that Site-core  is a Customer engagement platform and developer should provide flexibility to it. Cheers. :)

Comment: Well explained answer. I would like to add that content authors often get confused if there are fields that do not get rendered visually on the page. They will assume something is broken because these values are not something they can visibly see on the page. Also, think of the implications of content editors seeing these values, how likely is it that your content authors could enter an invalid value? You would want security restrictions so that only certain users have the power to modify these fields